# Setting Custom Editor shows kendoDropDownList is not a function

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown, kendo-ui-vue

We like to use dropdown inside the grid, so we using this (https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/grid/editing/#toc-setting-custom-editors) example in our project we are getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).appendTo(...).kendoDropDownList is not a function
>       at VueComponent.categoryDropDownEditor (git.vue?26ca:154)

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: i'm using web-pack 3.11.0

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question it may helpful for someone

by adding kendo.all.min.js it working fine :)

But don't know why it wont included in default kendo vue.

```
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```